# How to quickly whiten teeth

Tags: personal-care, efficiency

I need a way to whiten my teeth quickly. I've used white strips before, but I didn't really like them as they didn't work well. I've also used whitening toothpaste, but those usually take over 2 weeks to work. **What is a way that I can whiten my teeth quickly?** By quickly I mean within two days. Also, I don't want to do anything that might damage my teeth.

*<sup>Note: My teeth aren't extremely yellow, but they are definitely not white</sup>*

Answer (score 3):

Try lemon juice and baking soda. Mix together and apply to teeth. Rinse off after a little while and don't use too frequently as this may cause tooth damage as any acids aren't good for teeth. But if you use very little lemon it should be alright.

---

Try using peroxide which is an ingredient of many teeth products. Brush and rinse with it, rinse cleanly. And don't use to often, it is actually a bleaching agent for hair and etc, but use in moderation.

Comment: Lemon juice could be disastrous. Generally available peroxide can't work in 2 days.

Comment: Any peroxide that would work in 2 days would remove more than just yellow color from your mouth.

Comment: "*Try lemon juice and baking soda*" baking soda with lemon juice undergo neutralisation reaction leaving you with some salt (chemical therm) and the one of them that was more concentrated.

Comment: won't the lemon juice attack your enamel ? It will get whiter but only because you burned the top layer off.

Answer (score 1):

I did it with baking soda and mixed in water to create a thick paste. Then apply to toothbrush and apply. You will not see and instant whiteness but you will definitely feel the clean feeling afterwards. Don't do more than 2-3 times a month. Perhaps consider an enamel repair toothpaste to use at the same time to counteract any damage you might be doing.